# Memory Leaks in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, c++11, memory-leaks

I have a memory leaks with this simple code using std::thread on Visual Studio Pro 2012:

```
#include <thread>

void f(){}

int main(){
    std::thread t(f);
    t.join();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;}
```

Win32 Output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{293} normal block at 0x00A89520, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

x64 Output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{293} normal block at 0x00000000003FCB00, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

If I comment the two first lines of the main method, I have no memory leaks.

Where does it come from ?

**EDIT: The leak is still here with that code:**

```
#include <thread>

void f(){}

int main(){
    {
        std::thread t(f);
        t.join();
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CrtDumpMemoryLeaks is notoriously unreliable. It may well be that the standard library intentionally leaks a one-time allocation when you first use std::thread. To find out if there's a real memory leak, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
  std::thread t(f); t.join();
}
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

And then see if the leak size increases as you increase LIMIT. If it doesn't, you're fine.

Comment: You are right, the leak does not increase with the number of threads launched.

Comment: @Arnaud Then it's probably a static one-time allocation and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

When you dump the leaks the thread destructor has not yet run. You should try:

```
int main()
{
  {
    std::thread t(f);
    t.join();
  }
  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing but the memory leaks is still here.

Comment: @Arnaud But you should edit the question with this version, anyway. In the one you posted it is not clear that these objects are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the thread object allocates some data, and as the destructor hasn't run when you dump the memory it's counted as a leak.

Try putting the thread object, creation and join in a separate function.

Comment: It happens also if I put the thread part in a function: void g(){std::thread t(f);t.join();}

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to call CrtDumpMemoryLeaks at that spot -- or if you do accept pseudo-leaks.

The destructors of static objects did not yet run, and such objects can sit on memory. 
If you use MFC it will run leak dump from dtor of AFX_STATE object that is notmally late enough to see only real leaks.

In the meantime you can use [_crtBreakAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2fhc9a3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to see where that block is allocated, I bet the call stack will lead you to some function-local static in the RTL territory and you can even set a breakpoint on its dtor to see it actually releases the memory a little after your dump.